# Is this duplication in constructors with initializer lists really necessary?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

Am I using initializer lists correctly in my class? There seems to be a lot of code duplication. If I needed another variable, I'd have to add it in three places.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(
        anotherClass _a,
        std::string _b,
        std::string _c,
        float _d
        )
        : a(_a),
        b(_b),
        c(_c),
        d(_d)
    { }
private:
    anotherClass a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
    float d;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you are using it correctly.

Comment: The good thing about initializer list is that it chooses the best constructor for the object. In your case, all members are initialized by their copy constructor because the _a, _b ,... are of the same type of a, b,... However, this is not required. If your anotherClass has a constructor that takes one argument, then you can do a(_N) where _N is whatever that constructor takes. Simply put, it's equivalent to "anotherClass a(X);", and you are not duplicating code, you are just dividing them into parts and put some of them into a different place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of initializer lists is correct but it's pretty dubious as to what the point of this class is. You could just make all the members public and then use aggregate or uniform initialization to initialize each member. If you actually need not-shown complex semantics, then there is nothing wrong with this use of init lists.

Comment: The point of the class is to demonstrate the issue without any needless clutter. I think it fulfills it admirably.

Answer (score 2):

If you end up having a class, that
1) Have a constructor sending in all its data,
2) have getters for all members and
3) have setters for all members,
you should probably go for a struct with no private members.

Then you can use 'uniform initialization' like:
`MyX x{"hello",5.5};`
Without having to write a constructor.

If this is not the case (your class actually have an invariant) then 
yes, you have to add a thing in 3 places when adding a member.

Note, that due to scope rules, the following works:

```
class A {
    int mem;
public:
    A(int mem) : mem(mem) {}
};
```

no underscore needed.

Comment: Thanks. There are no setters or getters, all the members are set at construction. There are a couple of public methods that I didn't list though.